# Java array data corruption in callback

Tags: java

this code is giving me some problems. This's simply the thread portion of a Service that receive data sent trough a TCP connection. This data is an image (160x120x16bpp = 38400 bytes) feed to an Activity trough a callback.

```java
public void run() {
    InetAddress serverAddr;
    link_respawn = 0;

    try {
        serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(VIDEO_SERVER_ADDR);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    Socket socket = null;
    DataInputStream stream;

    do {
        bad_frames = 0;
        frames = 0;
        status = FrameDecodingStatus.Idle;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, VIDEO_SERVER_PORT);

            stream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

            final byte[] _data = new byte[PACKET_SIZE];
            final byte[] _image_data = new byte[IMAGE_SIZE];
            int _data_index = 0;

            while (keepRunning) {
                if (stream.read(_data, 0, _data.length) == 0)
                    continue;

                for (byte _byte : _data) {
                    if (status == FrameDecodingStatus.Idle) {
                        if (_byte == SoF) {
                            status = FrameDecodingStatus.Data;
                            _data_index = 0;
                        }
                    } else if ((status == FrameDecodingStatus.Data) && (_data_index < IMAGE_SIZE)) {
                        _image_data[_data_index] = _byte;
                        _data_index++;
                    } else if ((status == FrameDecodingStatus.Data) && (_data_index == IMAGE_SIZE)) {
                        if (_byte == EoF) {
                            if(frameReadyCallBack!=null)
                                frameReadyCallBack.frameReady(_image_data);
                            frames++;
                            status = FrameDecodingStatus.Idle;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            link_respawn++;
            Thread.sleep(VIDEO_SERVER_RESPAWN);
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Link respawn: " + link_respawn);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (keepRunning);

    if (socket != null) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the *Android* `Activity` that receive the callback find data in array *corrupted* in a very strange way .. i.e. starting at a certain index data into array is set to 0.
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` is not `readFully`. Three-arg `read` returns the number of bytes that has been read, which is not necessary the full length of the array supplied.

This codes drops the `read` return value and process the entire array.

```
            if (stream.read(_data, 0, _data.length) == 0)
                continue;

            for (byte _byte : _data) {
```

Comment: well I think I got it. `for` cycle should iterate for the number of bytes actually read from `stream.read` function right?

Comment: or using `readFully()` of course but in my case I prefer the first approach.